# bounce an image in to view

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I have some code which works nicely and acts like a menu appearing when you click a button. I just want to animate slightly. So when it appears, it appears to bounce in. Here's the code which shows it

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"theAnimation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(yourAnimationHasFinished:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.3];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
scrollChangeClothing.transform = moveUp;
imgClothesMenuBg.transform = moveUp;
[UIView commitAnimations];  

[UIView beginAnimations:@"theAnimation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(yourAnimationHasFinished:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.1];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
scrollChangeClothing.transform = moveUp;
imgClothesMenuBg.transform = moveUp;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

the code above (I thought) should first show the image at -20 pixels start point, then settle back to it's original point.

I tried combining the transform commands but that didnt work either. Do I need to put the second animation in the setAnimationDidStopSelector?? So once it's finished, it will then bounce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code doesn't work because the two animation blocks are coalesced behind the scene into one identity transform.

- Try removing the UIView animation methods from the first block, leaving only the lines below. This should make your views "slide into position".

  CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
  scrollChangeClothing.transform = moveUp;
  imgClothesMenuBg.transform = moveUp;
- Try enclosing both blocks in an outer +beginAnimations:context:/+commitAnimations block if you do need to animate "sliding out".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should move your second animation block into the first's animationDidStop method.