# Using CAKeyFrameAnimation (or something else?) to make image bounce with RubyMotion

Tags: ios, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation, rubymotion

I am new to Core Animation and new to RubyMotion (have been working with Obj-C in Xcode since January). I'm needing to have the AppLabel (the png for it is specified in file called AppAppearance.rb but all animation for it loading is in this file). Right now I'm using animateWithDuration but I need a bit of a bounce to the left when the label loads. Any possible help on this would be super appreciated, I've been going around in circles all day. I'm trying to use the code from this: [bounce an image in to view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048757/1381375) and anything I can find on CAKeyFrameAnimation but I am getting stuck on converting Obj-C to Ruby. Thanks!

```
class AppLabel < UILabel
#-------------------------


  DefaultHeight =                 45
  DefaultWidth =                  170               


  def initWithFrame( frame )
  #-------------------------

    if ( super( frame ) )


      @showing = false
      @hiding = false


      self.size.width = 170 if self.size.width == 0
      self.size.height = 46 if self.size.height == 0

      self.backgroundColor = AppAppearance.appLabelBackgroundColor
      self.font = AppAppearance.fontWithSize( 14 )
      self.textColor = AppAppearance.appLabelTextColor      

      self.numberOfLines = 2


    end

    self

  end


  #
  # method. drawTextInRect
  # 
  def drawTextInRect( rect )
  #-------------------------


    rect.origin.x += 10
    rect.origin.y += 2    
    rect.size.width -= 30

    super( rect )

  end

  #
  # method. show
  #
  def show
  #-------

    if ( ( self.hidden? || self.alpha < 1 ) && !@showing )

      if self.hidden?

          self.alpha = 0.0
          self.hidden = false

      end

      @showing = true

      UIView.animateWithDuration(
         1.0,
         animations: lambda do
           self.alpha = 1.0
         end,
         completion: lambda do | finished |
           @showing = false
         end
      )          

    end

  end

  #
  # method. hide
  #
  def hide
  #-------

    unless ( self.hidden? || self.alpha == 0 || @hiding )

      log( 'hiding' )

      @hiding = true

      UIView.animateWithDuration(
        1.0,
        animations: lambda do
          self.alpha = 0.0
        end,
        completion: lambda do | finished |
          self.hidden = true
          @hiding = false
        end
      )          

    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, the Procs are probably a bit overkill but it works! The timing's far from perfect but I'm sure you can work on that ;)

```
# view: The view to animate
# attrs:
#   times:    How many times the view should bounce
#   offset:   The distance to the left of the furthest (first) bounce
#   change:   How much to decrement the offset each bounce
#   duration: The duration of the furthest (first) bounce
def bounce(view, attrs={times: 4, offset: 20, change: 5, duration: 0.25})
  # The points to animate the view to
  @points = []

  attrs[:times].times do |n|
    new_x = view.position.x - (attrs[:offset] - n * attrs[:change])
    # Move the point left, then back to the original position
    @points << [new_x, view.position.y]
    @points << view.position
  end

  # An array to hold the blocks containing the animations
  @animations = [];

  # Needs an animation to move away then back
  (attrs[:times] * 2).times do |n|
    new_dur = (Float(attrs[:change]) / Float(attrs[:offset])) * (attrs[:times] * 2 - n) * attrs[:duration]
    # Add a new movement to the animations array
    @animations << Proc.new {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(new_dur,
        delay: 0,
        #Ease out when moving away and in when moving back
        options: (n % 2 == 0 ? UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut : UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn),
        animations: lambda {
          # Animate the view to the position at the start of the points array
          view.position = @points.first
        },
        completion: lambda { |completed|
          # Remove the first point and first animation from their corresponding
          # arrays then run the next animation until there are none left
          @animations.shift
          @points.shift
          @animations.first.call if @animations.length != 0
        })
    }
  end
  # Initiate the chain of animations
  @animations.first.call
end
```